# ExceptionHandler equivalent in Guice

Tags: guice, guice-3

I'm having Controller which can throw my Custom Exception.

```
public Response fetch(final String id) throws MyException {
    return Response.ok().entity(custonService.fetch(id)).build();
}
```

I want to handle that exception and set response status as bad request with custom message as it happen in spring with the help of ExceptionHandler. 
I saw CheckedProvider but couldn't find how to set response status and message in case of exception.
Is there a way to do so?
I'm new to Guice, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Guice thing. Guice is just a dependency injection framework, it doesn't have anything to do with REST APIs. It looks like you are using JAX-RS, which means to control the status code and body of an error response, you need to use the [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) system provided by JAX-RS.

On a separate note, you probably shouldn't be using a `Response` object. Just return the value and it will automatically get a `200 OK` status code.